# Object-oriented GUI development in python

Tags: python, user-interface, oop

Hey guys, new programmer here. I have an assignment for class and I'm stuck... What I need to do is a create a GUI that gives someone a basic arithmetic problem in one box, asks the person to answer it, evaluates it, and tells you if you're right or wrong...

Basically, what I have is this:

```
class Lesson(Frame):
    def __init__ (self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        Lesson.make_widgets(self)

    def make_widgets(self):
        Label(self, text="").pack(side=TOP)

        ent = Entry(self)
        self.a = randrange(1,10)
        self.b = randrange(1,10)
        self.expr = choice(["+","-"])

        ent.insert(END, str(self.a) + str(self.expr) + str(self.a))
```

I've broken this down into many little steps and basically, what I'm trying to do right now is insert a default random expression into the first entry widget. When I run this code, I just get a blank Label. Why is that? How can I put a something like "7+7" into the box? If you absolutely need background to the problem, it's question #3 on this link.

http://reed.cs.depaul.edu/lperkovic/csc242/homeworks/Homework8.html

-Thanks for all help in advance.

Comment: Don't use [code], use four-space indents.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change the Label or the contents of the Entry? I'll assume the latter. The short answer is

```
ent.delete(0, END)
ent.insert(END, 'stringy thing')
```

**but** nothing is going to change in the interface until the Tk() instance mainloop() method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Change the

```
text=""
```

in the Label object instantiation to

```
text="Label Text"
```

or what ever you want to show as the label.

Next add

```
ent.pack()
```

after your ent.insert in your make_widgets method.